# Follow all users on a twitter page

Tags: javascript, twitter, greasemonkey

I'm on https://twitter.com/#!/username/followers ; is there any greasemonkey script to follow all the twitter users on that page?

Comment: Is this your twitter account or someone else's?    You could write a GM script for twitter, but that site is an absolute nightmare, code-wise.  Meanwhile, twitter has API's and there are a variety of online tools that may already do what you want. For example, check out [Tweepi](http://tweepi.com/).

Comment: It's my account. Thanks a lot for Tweepi tool ! I'll start use it

Comment: `avascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('button-text follow-text'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }` from http://www.talktohacker.com/2014/09/mass-followers-twitter-script-for-1000.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a new one which also employs a delay to prevent spam issues.

```
var FOLLOW_PAUSE = 1250;
var FOLLOW_RAND = 250; 
var PAGE_WAIT = 2000;
__cnt__ = 0; 
var f;
f = function() {
        var eles;
        var __lcnt__ = 0;
        eles = jQuery('.Grid-cell .not-following .follow-text').each(function(i, ele) {
                    ele = jQuery(ele);
                    if (ele.css('display') != 'block') {
                        console.trace('Already following: ' + i);
                        return;
                    }
                    setTimeout(function() {
                              console.trace("Following " + i + " of " + eles.length);
                            ele.click();
                            if ((eles.length - 1) == i) {
                                console.trace("Scrolling...");
                                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    f();
                                }, PAGE_WAIT);
                            }
                    }, __lcnt__++ * FOLLOW_PAUSE + Math.random()*(FOLLOW_RAND) - FOLLOW_RAND/2);
                    __cnt__++;
        });
}
f();
```

What it does:

- Looks for follow buttons
- Checks that you aren't already following or pending (`display: block` check)
- Sets a timer to click the FOLLOW buttons every 500ms to prevent spam issues.
- NEW! When it's done them all, scrolls the page and waits a couple seconds for the next loads to appear, then repeats the whole process!

Notes for hackers:

- Works on Chrome latest version and Twitter as of the 30th of Sep 2016.
- You seem to need to "click" the DIV inside the A tag, not the A tag itself.
- HOMEWORK:  Maybe try jQuery's live() function to auto-click any new buttons which show up after the initial page load :)

Disclaimer:  This is not a hack...just a technique to save some wrist and finger RSI :)  Regardless, use cautiously and respectfully.

UPDATE: Improved for latest twitter. Now employs randomness in the timing to make you look less like a bot

Comment: Be VERY cautious.  I just had my account suspended for what I would have thought was modest use...

Comment: I try to use it, but I have:

`VM235:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)f @ VM235:7(anonymous function) @ VM235:26`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same error than @AndrewKachalin. I did my own script, but It just work for few times:
`(function () {
    'use strict';
    var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
        var boton = botones.item(i);
        var child = boton.children[0];
        if (child.className = "button-text follow-text") {
            boton.click();
        }
    }
})();`

Comment: I ran my own script until Twitter limited to me:
`(function () {
    'use strict';
    var contenedores = document.getElementsByClassName('not-following');
    for (var i = 0; i < contenedores.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < contenedores.length; j++) {
            var contenedor = contenedores[j];
            var botones = contenedor.getElementsByClassName('follow-button');
            for (var k = 0; k < botones.length; k++) {
                var boton = botones.item(k);
                boton.click();
            }
        }
    }
})();`

Comment: How to "unfollow" automagically?

Answer (score 4):

Twitter uses JQuery, so a way to do this, assuming that you aren't doing this so much as to trigger the rate limits (the rate limits will apply more aggressively to web client users as compared to API users) is to do the equivalent of:

```
$('.button.follow-button').click()
```

You can accomplish this in GreaseMonkey if you'd like, or setting it as a JavaScript bookmarklet, or by copy-pasting this into your address bar and hitting enter:

```
javascript:$('.button.follow-button').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified the code that Hari Karam Singh posted earlier to work to the to-date Twitter.

```
__cnt__=0; jQuery('.stream button.follow-button > span.follow-text').each(function (i, ele) { ele = jQuery(ele); if (ele.css('display')!='block') {console.log('already following:', i); return;} setTimeout(function () {ele.click();}, __cnt__++*500); });
```

Comment: It appears to be out of date again now :(

Comment: I tried this:

__cnt__=0; jQuery('button.user-actions-follow-button > span.follow-text').each(function (i, ele) { ele = jQuery(ele); if (ele.css('display')!='block') {console.log('already following:', i); return;} setTimeout(function () {ele.click();}, __cnt__++*500); });

Answer (score 1):

It doesn´t work anymore, but if you use the object instead of the alias i´ll do javascript:`jQuery('.button.follow-button').click();`.
You can also use the in-built debugger in chrome or firebug to add a button that cam do this for you, and add a `settimeout` to avoid interference with the api's restrictions.

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:jQuery('.button.follow-button').click();" value="follow!
">
```