# Bookmarklet: Click All Like Buttons On Tumblr

Tags: javascript, click, bookmarklet, tumblr

Similar to this
[Follow all users on a twitter page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841118/follow-all-users-on-a-twitter-page),
I am trying to change this to click all the "like" hearts on a Tumblr page instead of the follow button:

```
javascript:$('.button.follow-button').click()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
javascript:var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); var b = []; for(var i=0, len = a.length; i < len; i++){ if(a[i].id.indexOf('like_button') !== -1){b.push(a[i]) } }; for(var i=0, len = b.length; i < len; i++){ b[i].onclick() };
```

There. What it does is gets all the a tags on the page. Then filters them and finds all the like buttons. Then it just clicks on them.

Note that this solution is pretty inefficient and you should probably be using `document.getElementsByClassName` as Samuel did, but that may not be supported in all browsers (I'm looking at you, IE 8).

Comment: Add a javascript: before that code. I just added it. Try it now

Comment: You've just got to learn JavaScript. Learn JS from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/). If you want to learn how to do something like this, you want to just look for what's common between all of the buttons you want to click. Then you can just Google and find selectors. Like if they all have common CSS class names, you can google, 'CSS class name selector JavaScript' and you'd find `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Amaan Why are you glaring at IE8 when you can just use `document.querySelectorAll(".myclass")`, which is several times faster than `getElementsByClassName` anyway?

Comment: @Kolink I must have forgotten about `querySelectorAll`, but who told you it was faster? It's a lot slower in all browsers except Opera. [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/5)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your bookmarklet:

```
javascript:e=document.getElementsByClassName('like_button');for(i=0;i<e.length;i++){e[i].click();}void(0);
```

Edit: the above only works in Firefox. Try this instead:

```
javascript:e=document.getElementsByTagName('a');for(i=0;i<e.length;i++){if(e[i].id.indexOf('like_button')>=0)e[i].click();}void(0);
```