# JavaScript/Bookmarklet to click all "add to friends" buttons on Facebook (mass/bulk befriend)

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, button, click

I want to add to my friends all profiles shown on a Facebook page. I've seen [Bookmarklet: Click All Like Buttons On Tumblr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175822/bookmarklet-click-all-like-buttons-on-tumblr) and I was trying something like

```
 javascript:e=document.getElementsByTagName('a');for(i=0;i<e.length;i++) {if(e[i].id.indexOf('addButton')>=0)e[i].click();}void(0);
```

because that's the class of the a elements in the buttons, which are like

```
<a class="uiIconText addButton" style="padding-left: 18px;"><i class="img sp_7b7xx5 sx_a97ca4" style="top: 2px;"></i>Aggiungi agli amici</a>
```

(in Italian).
But nothing happens (and I'm using Firefox). The a element appears to be empty, where is the actual link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to approach the `id` attribute, while what you're really looking for is the elements's `class`.

try replacing `if(e[i].id.indexOf('addButton')>=0)` with `if(e[i].className.indexOf('addButton')>=0)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but I also need it to wait at least 10 s before each click. I've tried this:

    javascript:e=document.getElementsByTagName('a');for(i=0;i<e.length;i++) {if(e[i].className.indexOf('addButton')>=0)setTimeout(function() {e[i].click();},10000);}void(0);